# Где лучше размещать php файлы?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, http

Где лучше размещать php-скрипты и фалы к которым доступ должен не предоставляются по http? Вне корневого каталога веб-сайта? Или лучше их помещать в каталог веб-сайта и закрыть доступ при помощи .htaccess?

Comment: Есть какие-то причины так делать? Можно создать папку с такими файлами и закрыть её от чтения в htaccess. В получаемой странице всё равно нет никаких следов с именем этого файла, а ошибки на работающем сайте принято отключать error_reporting(0)

Comment: Следует помнить, что ".htaccess" не имеет отношения к РНР, и наличие этого файла совершенно не гарантированно.

Comment: @Adokenai error_reporting(0) даже на работающем сайте - плохая идея. Вы искренне надеетесь что ошибок вообще не будет?

Comment: @tutankhamun для сайтов есть логи. Незачем пользователю выдавать лишнюю информацию.

Comment: @Adokenai это распространенное заблуждение. Данная функция отвечает не за то, что делать с ошибками, а за уровень ошибок. Который должен быть всегда только E_ALL. А выводом занимается совсем другая настройка. Для справки: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting – Ипатьев 1 час назад   удалить

Comment: @tutankhamun  Я про скрытие имён файлов написал, а не про отключение ошибок, просто неправильно выразил мысль.

Comment: @Adokenai Насчет файлов вопросов нет. Я зацепился за "а ошибки на работающем сайте принято отключать `error_reporting(0)`". Я не могу себе представить когда `error_reporting(0)` может быть полезен. Надеюсь вы перепутали с параметром конфигурации `display_errors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильней будет размещать их вне дерева каталогов веб сайта. Всегда есть вероятность ошибиться в htaccess или конфигурации, а так никакая ошибка или эксплойт доступа к файлам не даст (по крайней мере через http). Надежно и главное, с точки зрения затрат ничего не стоит.